# Is it possible to document or add comments to a scriptin file?

Tags: normal-mode

I have a lengthy scriptin that I'm using to help me convert JavaScript files to Typescript. There are about 30 commands defined in it so far:

```
:%s/^\(\s*\)params\.\(\S\+\) = \(.*\);/\1  \2: \3,/
:g/function/s/\<e\>,/_event: Event | null/
:g/function/s/\<e\>/_event?: Event | null/
:%s/\<e\>/event/g
[...]
```

It's getting to the point where it's difficult, particularly for other team members who aren't familiar with regex, to know what any of it does. I'd like to be able to document it for their and my sanity.

Is that possible?

Is it possible to make a comment in a scriptin? I.e., is there a command that when entered will allow any number of keys to be pressed until <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or some other comment terminator) is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, use double-quotes

[`:h :comment`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3acomment)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!